# Referencia sin definir en C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Llevo varios días con el mismo error, "referencia a 'Container::nextId' sin definir".

**El .h**

```
class Container

friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, const Container& obj);


protected:
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int value;
    unsigned int weight;
    static unsigned int nextId;
    static const unsigned int kMINWEIGHT = 100;
    static const unsigned int kMINVALUE = 100;

public:
    Container(unsigned int weight, unsigned int value);
    void static resetNextId();
    unsigned int getId() const;
    unsigned int getValue() const;
    unsigned int getWeight() const;
    void setWeight(unsigned int weight);
    void setValue(unsigned int value);
```

Y la declaración del método donde da error, en el **.cc**:

```
void Container::resetNextId(){

    Container::nextId = 1;

}
```

He buscado mucha información, y parece ser que el error proviene de modificar el atributo nextId, que es static. He probado todo tipo de cosas, pero no logro averiguar como solucionarlo. El error se produce en la línea donde aparece 'Container::nextId = 1;'

Gracias de antemano, y un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los datos estáticos de clase deben ser definidos fuera de la clase:

```
class Container {

friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, const Container& obj);


protected:
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int value;
    unsigned int weight;
    static unsigned int nextId;
    static const unsigned int kMINWEIGHT = 100;
    static const unsigned int kMINVALUE = 100;

public:
    Container(unsigned int weight, unsigned int value);
    void static resetNextId();
    unsigned int getId() const;
    unsigned int getValue() const;
    unsigned int getWeight() const;
    void setWeight(unsigned int weight);
    void setValue(unsigned int value);
};

unsigned int Container::nextId = 1;
unsigned int Container::kMINWEIGHT = 100;
unsigned int Container::kMINVALUE = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

El código que proporcionas no debería fallar. He probado a compilarlo en mi equipo y compila bien. Lo único que falta son los corchetes de la clase en el **.h** que quedaría así

```
class Container {

friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, const Container& obj);


protected:
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int value;
    unsigned int weight;
    static unsigned int nextId;
    static const unsigned int kMINWEIGHT = 100;
    static const unsigned int kMINVALUE = 100;

public:
    Container(unsigned int weight, unsigned int value);
    void static resetNextId();
    unsigned int getId() const;
    unsigned int getValue() const;
    unsigned int getWeight() const;
    void setWeight(unsigned int weight);
    void setValue(unsigned int value);
};
```

Comment: No tienes idea de porque puede aparecer el error? Más concretamente es este:
**g++ -Wall -g Base.o Ship.o Container.o Util.o prac3.o -o prac3
Container.o: En la función `Container::resetNextId()':
/home/luis/Escritorio/Cpp/Practica 3/autocorrector-prac3/src/Container.cc:90: referencia a `Container::nextId' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:6: recipe for target 'prac3' failed
make: *** [prac3] Error 1**

Comment: De echo, en cualquier parte del Container.cc donde hago referencia a 'nextId' me aparece el mismo error, como por ejemplo:
`id = nextId`
o
`nextId++`